# Trying to concatenate 2 values into a hidden field

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to convert a date from a datepicker into fields that can be passed to a booking engine. This engine takes 2 values 
checkOutDate = DD
checkOutMonthYear = MMYYYY

So far I have created a form with some hidden fields and have been trying to use this script to update the fields. The checkOutDate works OK, but I cannot work out how to concatenate the 2 values (and also how to check for a month '1' and turn it into '01')

```
  <script>
  $('#date').on('change', function() {
     var new_val = $(this).val().split('-'),
         dateYear = parseInt(new_val[0]),
         dateMonth = parseInt(new_val[1]),
         dateDay = parseInt(new_val[2]);

    $('input[id=checkOutDate]').val(dateDay);
    $('input[id=checkInMonthYear]').val(dateMonth);    

 });
 </script>
```

I tried + and .add but have to admit a bit lost, so would appreciate some suggestions

Comment: I don't understand. Where do you try to concatenate anything? And if you're trying to operate on strings, why are you parsing them as ints? And `$('#checkInMonthYear')` is a lot shorter.

Comment: You are right, I posted the code of where I was up to before failing with the next step, so there wasn't an example of my rubbish attempts - sorry to confuse, should have made clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for a month '1' and turn it into '01':

```
    dM=(dateMonth<=9)?'0'+dateMonth:dateMonth+'';
```

now you have a string variable dM, you can do the same with dateYear creating dY, then you just use `dM+dY` to create your 'MMYYYY' string

```
 $('#date').on('change', function() {
 var new_val = $(this).val().split('-'),
     dateYear = parseInt(new_val[0]),
     dateMonth = parseInt(new_val[1]),
     dateDay = parseInt(new_val[2]);

     dM=(dateMonth<=9)?'0'+dateMonth:dateMonth+'';
     dY=dateYear+'';

     $('#checkOutDate').val(dateDay);
     $('#checkInMonthYear').val(dM+dY);    
 });
```

Comment: Excellent, that seems to do it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in javascript ocncation is using concat method

this is a demo code for concat string

var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#date').on('change', function() {
 var new_val = $(this).val().split('-');
$('#checkOutDate).val(new_val[0]);
$('#checkInMonthYear').val(new_val[1]+new_val[2]);  
});
```

For month display(1 to 01)you can set dateformat(dd-mm-yyyy) in ur datepicker